# C# Selenium WebDriver - Is it possible to check if a certain webpage is already opened in the browser?

Tags: c#, selenium, browser, automation, webdriver

I was wondering if it is possible to check with C# and selenium web driver if a certain webpage is opened in the default browser?
My idea is to link certain ticketing system's time tracker with toggl.

For instance - on click of the "Time Track" button in the ticketing system, the program to click the toggl start button programmatically, at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

You can devise a solution that checks the default window's URL or title.

```
if (driver.Url == 'http://some_url') { /* you are there */ }
```

or

```
if (driver.Title == 'Some Title') { /* the window is open and currently there */ }
```

Now, if you are running a browser manually using your own browser, then expect Selenium to detect *that*, then i'm sorry, but *that* is not possible.

Comment: Thank you i will try it!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @sircapsalot answer:

This won't be enough since the goal is to

> on click of the "Time Track" button in the ticketing system

First you should be sure that the page has been loaded and the `IWebElement` is clickable. Without going in some advanced usage (like JS validation of the page state), this should do the work just fine:

```
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
 var myElement = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Id("timeTrackBtnId")));
 if(myElement.Displayed)
 myElement.Click();
```

Then go for the

> program to click the toggl start button programmatically, at the same time

I'm not sure how you'll sync and how page's JS events will handle this simultaneous actions, but you can try with [System.Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading(v=vs.110).aspx). If the page is created by you maybe this second part (click button, click togl) is better to be handled in the JS code.